# this.set is not a function

Tags: javascript, annyang

I have code like this:

```
var ws2812 = {};


ws2812.set = function(r,g,b){
    $.get( "/light?r="+r+"&g="+g+"&b="+b, function( data ) {
        console.log("Light set to:"+"/light?r="+r+"&g="+g+"&b="+b);
    })
};

ws2812.speech = function(word){
    switch(word){
        case "czerwone":
            this.set(255,0,0);
        break;
        case "zielone":
            this.set(0,255,0);
            break;
        case "niebieskie":
            this.set(0,0,255);
            break;
        case "białe":
            this.set(255,255,255);
            break;
        default:
            this.set(0,0,0);
            break;

    }
}
```

When running `ws2812.speech("");` inside console, everything works. However, when paired with the `Annyang` library, I get this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.set is not a function 
ws2812.speech @ script.js:29  
b.annyang.init.d.onresult @ annyang.min.js:6
```

What's wrong?

[edit]

The command is added like this:

```
annyang.addCommands({"ustaw *term światło":ws2812.speech});
```

Specifically, inside annyang, this line fails:

```
f[h].callback.apply(this,m)
```

Is replacing `this` with `ws2812` the only way to work around this?

Comment: are you passing the unbound `speech` function as a callback? Please include the code that *fails* in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*ws2812.speec is defined as a static function*. So `this` keyword inside it refers to itself (function scope), not the object *ws2812* you want.

To fix it, either of these quick choices can be made:

---

**Choice#1 > Call the static function ws2812.set properly**

So your code becomes:

```
ws2812.speech = function(word){
    switch(word){
    case "czerwone":
        ws2812.set(255,0,0);
    break;
    case "zielone":
        ws2812.set(0,255,0);
        break;
    case "niebieskie":
        ws2812.set(0,0,255);
        break;
    case "białe":
        ws2812.set(255,255,255);
        break;
    default:
        ws2812.set(0,0,0);
        break;

    }
}
```

However, there are some possibilities that `this` keywords referenced in other parts in the rest of the code may also suffer from this issue. You may need to go check it.

---

**Choice#2 > Convert to prototype functions**

This way you can retain `this` keywords, but the functions are no longer static. You need to instantiate an instance object of `ws2812` to use.

So your declarations becomes:

```
var ws2812 = function(){};


ws2812.prototype.set = function(r,g,b){
    $.get( "/light?r="+r+"&g="+g+"&b="+b, function( data ) {
        console.log("Light set to:"+"/light?r="+r+"&g="+g+"&b="+b);
    })
};

ws2812.prototype.speech = function(word){
    switch(word){
    case "czerwone":
        this.set(255,0,0);
    break;
    case "zielone":
        this.set(0,255,0);
        break;
    case "niebieskie":
        this.set(0,0,255);
        break;
    case "białe":
        this.set(255,255,255);
        break;
    default:
        this.set(0,0,0);
        break;

    }
}
```

Then use it via instance of object instead:

```
var myWs2812 = new ws2812();
myWs2812.speech('hello world!'); // inside it, should call this.set properly
```

---

**Choice#3 > Bind 'this' object when calling**

In case you insist you don't want to modify the implementation of this `ws2812`. It's okay to leave it and *bind this object when using it instead*.

So when you call `ws2812.speech`, you need to use `function.prototype.call` and pass in `ws2812.set` as this.

```
ws2812.call( ws2812.set, 'hello world!' );
```

However, this doesn't look much semantic and it may cause confusions in the future use for people who will maintain this code.

---

I'll leave it for you to decide which would be the best way for you to go.